# resolution issue in cordova android app

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using cordova with jquery mobile for one android app.
For Viewport meta tag i am using below code

```html
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0;user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

With older jquery mobile version it was returning actual height and width of device but when i have upgraded jquery mobile to 1.4.5 and cordova to 5.0 then it is returning some different resolution with window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

Based on this resolution i am taking css files with media query

Please help me with this

Regards,
Bindal

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround:

- In index.html: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">`
- In index.css the "body" part, add: `transform-origin: 0px 0px; transform: scale(0.5);`

window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth has the native resolution.

But haven't run test if one pixel is one pixel. Also I don't have enough device to test if it works across different device and different version of android.

Answer (score 0):

With this mets it works for me, try it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are the wrong approach for several reasons:

- you will not get an exact match for your screen, proportional layout is for some elements impossible
- You will not be able to target Android 4.0+. Quad-HD and older devices use the same proportion with different -device-pixel-ratio factors. Factors are interpreted differently through Android versions, so some displays will be messed up
- media queries are intended to supply DIFFERENT visuals for different resolutions, not the same visual scaled across resolutions

I recommend using https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-anyscreen (and drop jquery mobile). It will also give you the correct display and available resolution as `app.deviceWidth`, `app.deviceHeight` and `app.containerWidth`  etc.